# On Proving That a Primitive Does Not Exist

Tags: provable-security

In the [paper of Hsiao and Reyzin](http://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2004/CRYPTO/1414/1414.pdf), Section $1.4$:

> Note that to show that no *general* reduction from $P$ to $Q$ exists requires proving that $Q$ does not exist

Since the statement is about trying to *rule out* the implication $Q \rightarrow P$, showing that $Q$ does *not* exist will indeed do the opposite: it makes the implication true for the trivial reason that $(\mathsf{false} \rightarrow \mathsf{proposition})$ is $\mathsf{true}$ for any $\mathsf{proposition}$.

Could someone explain?

Comment: What makes you think "the statement is about trying to _rule out_ the implication $Q\to P$"? $\;\;\;$ It certainly seems like it's "about trying to _rule out_ the implication" $\: P\to Q \;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Reducing $P$ to $Q$ means existence of $Q$ implies that of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note that this attempted answer contains a significant amount of guessing and must not be considered reliable!)*

**If** one assumes "there is a general reduction from $P$ to $Q$" to mean "existence of $Q$ implies existence of $P$" (which is up to interpretation since the authors do not clearly define that term, but it seems somewhat reasonable), then the statement in question is *wrong*: Under this assumption, it can be reformulated as

> *If the existence of $Q$ does not imply the existence of $P$, then $Q$ does not exist.*

...whose contrapositive

> *If $Q$ exists, then the existence of $Q$ implies the existence of $P$.*

is equivalent to "*there is a reduction from $P$ to $Q$*", and this is clearly untrue in general.

---

My best guess is, still under the assumption mentioned in the beginning, that this is a simple typo and they actually meant

> Note that to show that no general reduction from $P$ to $Q$ exists requires proving that $P$ does not exist

...which is true (and still conveys the point they are trying to illustrate) since its contrapositive

> *If $P$ exists, then the existence of $Q$ implies the existence of $P$.*

is obviously a tautology.